# Need help printing result of __str__ function in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm working on a problem with classes, but I'm stuck on defining the `__str__` function so that returns the capitalized version of whatever text within the class. Currently I have an excruciatingly difficult code that works in PyCharm but not in my class's automatic checking system. Can I get some advice on how to fix this code?

```
class X(str):
    def __str__(self, name):
        name = str.capitalize('hello')
        self.name = 'hello'
        return name
b = X('hello')
print(b.__str__('hello'))
```

Comment: and how `self` works. There's a lot going on here.

Comment: `__str__` should almost certainly not have any side effect like modifying `self`.

Comment: You should also not be calling `__str__` explicitly; the purpose of the method is to define what `str(b)` means, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

`__str__` canonically doesn't accept any arguments.

Since you're subclassing `str`, you probably mean

```
class X(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.capitalize()

b = X('hello')
print(b.__str__())  
# or print(str(b))
# or print(b)
```

i.e. to override the `__str__` magic method in a way that uses the superclass `str`'s methods to work on the "intrinsic" string data of the object (which exists because you're subclassing `str`).

This prints out

```
Hello
```